# Problem with integral equations

Tags: integral-equations

I have solved an integral equation with the following methods:

```
Options[FredholmKind2]={Method->Automatic};
FredholmKind2[{a_,b_,lambda_,k_,g_},n_?IntegerQ,OptionsPattern[]]:=
     Block[{step,SI,GI,KMatrix,W,DMatrix,f,deltaX,delta},step=(b-a)/n;
  SI=Range[a,b,step];
  GI=g/@SI;
  KMatrix=Outer[k,SI,SI];
  W={step/2}~Join~ConstantArray[step,n-1]~Join~{step/2};
  DMatrix=DiagonalMatrix[W];
  f=If[OptionValue[Method]===NIntegrate,deltaX[x_?NumericQ]:=
     W.(k[x,#]&/@SI)-NIntegrate[k[x,y],{y,a,b}];
  (*If the integral is expensive ParallelMap is an option here*)delta=deltaX/@SI;
     Interpolation[
       Transpose@{SI,LinearSolve[IdentityMatrix[n+1]+
             lambda*(DiagonalMatrix[delta]-KMatrix.DMatrix),GI]}],
    Interpolation[
      Transpose@{SI,LinearSolve[IdentityMatrix[n+1]-
             lambda*(KMatrix.DMatrix),GI]}]];
f]

n=50;(*number of discretization*)a=0.;
b=1.;
lambda=-1.;
Kpart[x_,y_]:=With[{A=2},(A/2)*
    (BesselJ[1,A*(x+y)]-BesselJ[1,A*Abs[x-y]]-I*StruveH[1,A*(x+y)]+I*StruveH[1,A*Abs[x-y]])]
Gpart[x_]:=x;
f1=FredholmKind2[{a,b,lambda,Kpart,Gpart},n,Method->Automatic];
f2=FredholmKind2[{a,b,lambda,Kpart,Gpart},n,Method->NIntegrate];
(Plot[Evaluate@(#/@{f1[x],f2[x]}),{x,a,b},Frame->True,Axes->False,
    PlotStyle->{{Thick,Opacity@.45},{Dashed,Red}},
    PlotLegends->{"Automatic","NIntegrate"},ImageSize->400]&/@{Re,Im})
```

I now want to evaluate and then plot Ktt(A):

```
Ktt[A]=A^3*NIntegrate[x f2[x],{x,0,1}]
```

for A ranging from 0 to 10 with 0.01 step. This means that for all these values of A I must find the corresponding f2(x) and then the corresponding Ktt(A) and then put all the Ktt points into a plot. Is there a way to do this with matrices or maybe with a loop?

Comment: Are you saying you want to vary the `A` in the `Width` block?

Comment: I want for all the afforementioned values of A to calculate f2(x), keep it somewhere (maybe in a matrix) along with the corresponding A's and then for all these f2(x) and A values to calculate Ktt(A) and plot it. I'm not sure how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is getting close..

```
 Kpart[A_?NumericQ][x_, y_] := (A/2)*(BesselJ[1, A*(x + y)] -
                                BesselJ[1, A*Abs[x - y]] - 
                                I*StruveH[1, A*(x + y)] +
                                I*StruveH[1, A*Abs[x - y]])
 f2[A_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
     FredholmKind2[{a, b, lambda, Kpart[A], Gpart}, n, Method -> NIntegrate][x];

 Table[{A, A^3 NIntegrate[x f2[A, x] , {x, 0, 1}] } , {A, {0,.5,.75,1}}]
```

> {{0, 0.}, {0.5, 0.0398216 + 0.000646822 I}, {0.75, 
>     0.128327 + 0.00639912 I}, {1, 0.288862 + 0.0304291 I}}

The results are complex (and quite slow ) so I'm not sure what to plot..

```
 ListPlot[ Re@% , Joined -> True ]
```

[image]